# Cocos2d CCSpriteFrameCache: couldn't load texture file

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I am currently doing this Cocos2d tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

...and get the following error messages:

```
2011-12-30 16:36:28.536 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
2011-12-30 16:36:28.537 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:AnimBear_default.png.ccz in CCTextureCache
2011-12-30 16:36:28.537 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: couldn't load texture file. File not found: AnimBear_default.png.ccz
2011-12-30 16:36:28.538 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
2011-12-30 16:36:28.538 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:AnimBear_default.png.ccz in CCTextureCache
2011-12-30 16:36:28.539 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: couldn't load texture file. File not found: AnimBear_default.png.ccz
2011-12-30 16:36:28.540 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
2011-12-30 16:36:28.540 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:AnimBear_default.png.ccz in CCTextureCache
2011-12-30 16:36:28.541 AnimBear[11273:10a03] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCa[Switching to process 11273 thread 0x1410b]
[Switching to process 11273 thread 0x10a03]
che: Frame 'bear1.png' not found
2011-12-30 16:36:28.598 AnimBear[11273:10a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x17e4052 0x1975d0a 0x17d136e 0x17d2220 0xc1997 0x3fcf1 0xc16dd 0xc0d7c 0x828b0e 0x8298a6 0x838743 0x8391f8 0x82caa9 0x2798fa9 0x17b81c5 0x171d022 0x171b90a 0x171adb4 0x171accb 0x8292a7 0x82aa9b 0xc085f 0x2135)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

I have the following files in the Resource folder:

- AnimBear_default.png.ccz
- AnimBear_default.plist

The texture consists of eight(8) bears named Bear1.png - Bear8.png. I have bought and done the texture in Zwoptex, latest version.

The code looks like:

```
-(id) init {

if((self = [super init])) {

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"AnimBear_default.plist" textureFile:@"AnimBear_default.png.ccz"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"AnimBear_default.png.ccz"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8 ; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bear%d.png", i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bear1.png"];        
    _bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                       [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [_bear runAction:_walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_bear];


}
return self;

}
```

I am completely new to Cocos2d and have been trying to search the web and tried different things but with no success :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's the issue, but you have an error in your init method. You should put all your initialization within the `if((self = [super init])) {` block.

So remove the first two lines from your init block (as they seem to be redudant anyway):

```
-(id) init 
{
    if((self = [super init])) {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"AnimBear_default.plist" textureFile:@"AnimBear_default.png.ccz"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"AnimBear_default.png.ccz"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8 ; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bear%d.png", i]]];
        }

        CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bear1.png"];        
        _bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                           [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        [_bear runAction:_walkAction];
        [spriteSheet addChild:_bear];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: oh my fault i used those lines when i tested, i removed it now. tests show same result, obvious i do not load the sprites.

Comment: @PeterK Did you add the files to the XCode project (using "Add files")? Copying them to the Resource folder alone is not enough, you'll have to add them to the "Resource" group in XCode as well.

Comment: yes i did. Actually i think i solved it as i found out how to save the sprite sheet without compression (.ccz) and load that i got it to work.